# What is the recommended practice for generating unique IDs in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In SQL Server, we have the NEW_ID() function whenever we want to generate a unique ID. Sometimes, when it's difficult to assign a primary key(s), I use this to uniquely identify a row.

I'm now writing a kotlin android app where I need to store user info in a collection -> document. What is the recommended practice for generating unique IDs for each user? Should I use a simple incrementing value starting with 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore does not implement auto increment IDs for documents.  Implementing it yourself will incur a performance penalty - that simply does not scale the way the Firestore requires.

If you are adding new documents to a collection, and they don't already have natural IDs, the SDK will generate a random ID for you when you use the [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#add(java.lang.Object)) method on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference).  This is the preferred way to add new documents, and is covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

If you need ordering of those documents, you should add a field that you can use to order the query.  If you want time-based ordering, you should add a timestamp field with the current time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're authenticating user then i would recommend to go with the `UID` generated by firebase itself. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130629/10838454) for fetching `UID` for current user.

Else you can generate Unique ID just like we are using `push()` while using realtime database.

```
DocumentReference key;
key = db.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME").document();
UniqueID = key.getId();
```

Now you can use this `UniqueID` as document.

Answer (score 0):

If you're here looking for a Angular suggestion, you can do it:

service.ts

```
YourListRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<YourModel>;
private dbPath = '/yourRootCollection';

...
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.YourListRef= this.db.collection(this.dbPath)
      .doc('yourFbDocRef').collection('youFbCollection');
  }
...
  create(obj: YourModel): any {
    this.uidKey = this.db.createId(); //<-- creating UID

    if (this.uidKey != null && this.uidKey != '') {
      obj.id = this.uidKey //<-- using like object's id
      return this.YourListRef.doc(this.uidKey).set({ ...obj });
    }
  }
```